# Angular JS $locationChangeStart get next url route object

Tags: angularjs, authorization, angularjs-routing

I am trying to implement Authorization on my angular application, when a route is changed I want to check whether the route is authorized for user or not. I tried with `$routeChangeStart` but it does not prevents the event.

My current code:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if(current_user.is_logged_in){
            var route_object = next.route_object;
            if(!(route_object.route_roles)){
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here in my `next` object I am getting route_object which is set in my `$routeProvider`

```
var routes = object;
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when(url, {
                    templateUrl: "/users.html",
                    route_object: routes,
                    });
            });
```

`routes` is an object which is formed in my function, but when I use `$locationChangeStart` I am just getting url's of next and previous page,

How do I get the entire route object??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get the route parameter in an `$locationChangeStart` event listener like this:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    if(current_user.is_logged_in){
        var route_object = ($route.routes[$location.path()]).route_object; //This is how you get it
        if(!(route_object.route_roles)){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Then classic preventDefault method would do the work. Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iiJd4g5EiPa0M2mDWjWv?p=preview) that I wrote for something similar.

Comment: This is actually working for me but the issue is `$location.$$path` returns `/users` but inside my route I have URL as `/users/:id?`

Because of which I am getting an error.

Comment: This doesn't work. If $location.path is /user/10 then the route /user/:id can't be found.

Comment: fyi if you're using ui.router, you will need to use $stateChangeStart.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            title: 'Home',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            access: {
                isFree: true
            }
        })
        .when('/about-us', {
            title: 'About us',
            templateUrl: 'partials/aboutus',
            controller: 'AboutUsController',
            access: {
                isFree: true
            }
        })
        .when('/how-it-works', {
            title: 'How It Works',
            templateUrl: 'partials/howitworks',
            controller: 'HowItWorksController',
            access: {
                isFree: true
            }
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'users/login',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            access: {
                isFree: true
            }
        })
        .when('/logout', {
            controller: 'LogoutController',
            access: {
                isFree: false
            }
        })
        .when('/sign-up', {
            templateUrl: 'users/signup',
            controller: 'SignUpController',
            access: {
                isFree: true
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
})


.run(['$rootScope', '$location','$log','$window','Auth' ,function($rootScope, $location, $log, $window, Auth) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, currRoute, prevRoute){
        $rootScope.title = '';
        if(currRoute.$$route.title !== undefined){
            $rootScope.title = currRoute.$$route.title ;
        }
      //  $rootScope.userLoggedIn = {name : 'Hi, '+ 'Amar'}    

        let checkIsLoggedInForRoute = ['/login','/sign-up'];
        let isFreeAccess = currRoute.$$route.access.isFree;
        let isLoggedIn = Auth.isLogin();

        if(isFreeAccess){
            if(checkIsLoggedInForRoute.indexOf($location.path()) !== -1 && isLoggedIn){
                event.preventDefault();
                $location.path('/')   
            }
        }else if(!isFreeAccess){
            let isLogoutRoute = currRoute.$$route.originalPath.indexOf('/logout') !== -1;
            if(isLogoutRoute && isLoggedIn){
                Auth.logout();           
                $location.path('/');    
            }else if(isLogoutRoute && !isLoggedIn){ 
                $location.path('/login');
            } 
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! How does this answer improve the already existing, accepted answer?

Comment: You can improve the Quality of this Answer by adding a description of how this answer works and thus how it improves the Questioner's situation.

Answer (score 0):

What is contained in next.$$route?

There should be a next.$$route.route_object

Comment: Inside `$locationChangeStart` `next` is just a string.

Comment: No, don't use $locationChangeStart... $routeChangeStart is where you want to be:

    `$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(next.$$route, null, 4));

        if(current_user.is_logged_in){
            var route_object = next.$$route.route_object;
            if(!(route_object.route_roles)){
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });`

Comment: Yaa that works, but I cannot prevent the event inside `$routeChangeStart`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to negate the event (as you're inside a function that was fired from a broadcast) ... but I found this that might help:

[link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5581)

Comment: Sorry, your question was: How do I get the entire route object?? That's all I tried to answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $location provider to do this like :

```
.run(['$rootScope','$location',function($rootScope,$location){
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event,next, current) {
       console.log('next',next);
       console.log('location',$location.path());
       console.log('location',$location.search()); // for route params
     });
    }])`
```