# confuse to parameters in listener function of $rootScope.$on()

Tags: angularjs

I am confused to parameters that use in the callback function below. Where event, next current parameters come from since the parameters are not called in the function at all?

```
 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
                    // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
                    var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
                    var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
                    if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular JS $locationChangeStart get next url route object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674714/angular-js-locationchangestart-get-next-url-route-object)

Comment: This might help you  https://ngcoderscope.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/accessing-methods-from-one-controller-to-another-in-angular-js/